# Firebase User sign up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

im very new to firebase 9. i just started out as a developer.
Could you please help me to understand the following:
User SignUp:
I am trying to create a user with email, password, displayName.

```
const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);

if (!res) {
  throw new Error("Could not complete signup");
}

//Upload user thumbnail
const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`;
const img = await addDoc(uploadPath).put(thumbnail);
const imgUrl = await img.ref.getDownloadURL();

// add display name to user
await res.user.updateProfile({ displayName, photoURL: imgUrl });

//create user document
await addDoc(
  collection(db, "users").doc(res.user.uid).set({
    online: true,
    displayName,
    photoURL: imgUrl,
  })
);

// dispatch login action
dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: res.user });
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: it follows firebase V8 


it doesn't work as i have updated to v9
im trying to convert it to firebase v9 using the new modular approach

Comment: It might be best if you share complete code showing how you have initialized Firebase and screenshots of the error you get.

Comment: The user successfully registers. Just the photo and displayname doesn't get stored, and there is no error showing

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { auth, db } from "../firebase/config";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { addDoc, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { useAuthContext } from "./useAuthContext";